# TurboPower LockBox 3 will not install in Delphi XE4 - error during compile

Tags: delphi, lockbox-3

I am trying to use LockBox 3 in Delphi XE4 to replace an encryption suite that has inexplicably stopped working.  I opened the Delphi project file and the three bpl's show up, but when I right-click and then choose install on LockBox3VCLDD240.bpl, it tries to compile and then gives the following error message:

[MSBuild Error] "0" is an invalid value for the "DebugInformation" parameter of the "DCC" task. The "DebugInformation" parameter is of type "System.Boolean".

I tried changing "Debug Information" to True in Project -> Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Linking, but the error still comes up.  Can anyone offer assistance?

Comment: Sounds like the wrong solution. Code doesn't just stop working. Stop flailing around in the dark and understand what you changed that broke your working code. Then fix that.

Comment: I didn't change anything in the code that is now not working.  I last compiled it two years ago.  I recompiled the same code last week, and it now does not work (when I say does not work, I don't mean it errors out - it runs but just doesn't decrypt correctly now).  I have wondered whether something with Windows Update is causing this problem - that's the only thing that changed on the computer.  I haven't touched the code since it last compiled and worked fine two years ago.

Comment: Windows update? Nope, it will be something you did.

Comment: The suffix 240 implies that it is a Delphi 10.1 Berlin version you are trying to open with your XE4. The project file format has changed in between. You may have more luck when you delete the dproj file and let the IDE create a new one.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments.  You might be right (your experience far exceeds mine).  Just wanted to follow up and say that the library that I was using was StreamFilters (a library written in 1998).  I had to make some small changes to it a couple of years ago to make it work with XE4 (I was previously at Delphi 6).  Those changes were around unicode.  I still don't know what happened with this library, but I switched it out for Lockbox3, and everything is working fine now with LB3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the above error message to go away by going to Project ->  Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Compiling and changing Debugging -> Debug Information to true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the new Delphi XE5 and up syntax (that uses "0" instead of "false" for `DebugInformation`) to Delphi XE4 or other versions you can edit  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\11.0\bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets` and append:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DCC_DebugInformation Condition=" '$(DCC_DebugInformation)'=='0' ">false</DCC_DebugInformation>
  <DCC_DebugInformation Condition=" '$(DCC_DebugInformation)'=='1' ">true</DCC_DebugInformation>
</PropertyGroup>
```

after the "Static Properties" block comment.

Using this trick is useful when you work with projects that must remain compatible with XE5 or upper and you don't want to edit the project debug configuration every time.